# Views, Taxonomy, multiple parameters using contextual filters

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

A view has been created to display related content types via their taxonomy terms, using contextual filters.
Currently the view is able to display content based on the first param  eg. about
The goal is to abe to display content based on the second param, being the child term and hide the parent eg. about/meet-the-team.

Here is a break down

Url :    page/parent term

parent term
    Content item referenced to parent term
    Content item referenced to parent term
    Content item referenced to parent term
    Content item referenced to parent term

Url: page/parent term/child term

child term
    Content item referenced to child term
    Content item referenced to child term
    Content item referenced to child term
        Content item referenced to child term
    Content item referenced to child term

Url: page/parent term/child term/child child term

```
Content item referenced to child child term
Content item referenced to child child term
Content item referenced to child child term
Content item referenced to child child term
Content item referenced to child child term
Content item referenced to child child term
Content item referenced to child child term
```

And this will continue on

Eg Url: page/parent term/child term/child child term/child child child term/child child child child term.

Answer (score 0):

To do like this too much *contextual filters* needed, i think it's better to manage the URL in [template.php](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21themes%21seven%21template.php/7) and/or with [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x) and use [views_embed_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7.x-3.x) to pass arguments to Views

```
$arg =array (1,2,3);
print views_embed_view('view_name', 'page_1', implode('+',$arg)); // OR
print views_embed_view('view_name', 'page_1', implode(',',$arg)); //AND
```